# Random key generation using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am using below function to generate 5 letters random key but it is the combination of all letters and numbers.

But as per requirements I need to generate a random unique key that does not contain the characters 'o' and 'I', and also does not contain the numbers  '0' and '1' .

```
   DECLARE @automateKey VARCHAR(15)
   DECLARE @Length INT = 6
   DECLARE @Count INT = 2

   SET @Length = @Length + 1
   SET @Count = @Count + 1

   SELECT @automateKey =  
          (SELECT CAST((ABS(Checksum(NewId())) % 10) AS VARCHAR(1)) + 
                  CHAR(ascii('A')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25)) +
                  LEFT(newid(),@count) Random_Number)

   SELECT (@automateKey)
```

I am not sure how I can escape the those particular characters and numbers from random key generation

Could anyone please help with this query? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you can check the final string if it contains any of 0,1 or O,L  then replace with some other letters

Comment: You mention random key rather than random value. Does the generated key need to be unique (i.e. no dups)? The solution will depend on that requirement.

Comment: yeah sorry to forgot it should be unique...

Comment: Just to clarify: You desire code to generate a _random_ string consisting of a single digit, a single uppercase letter and three additional digits. The digits `0` and `1` are forbidden, as are the letters `I` and `O`. The resulting string must be unique with respect to some unspecified list of previously issued strings. And the code must be usable within an `insert` statement. Does that cover everything? (Four values from 0 to 7, one from 0 and 23, mapped to strings of valid digits/letters. Concatenate, check `if exists( ? )`, repeat as needed. User-defined function (UDF)?)

Answer (score 2):

Use `RAND()` is better than `NEWID()`, as it is not random in nature.

```
DECLARE 
    @Chars varchar(100) = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
    @CharsAndNumbers varchar(100) = '23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'

SELECT 
    CONCAT
    (
        -- Numbers 2-9
        FLOOR(RAND() * 8 + 2),

        -- Any UPPER CASE character but not I,O
        SUBSTRING(@Chars, CONVERT(int, RAND() * LEN(@Chars) + 1), 1),

        -- Numbers 2-9 and Any UPPER CASE charcter but not I,O
        SUBSTRING(@CharsAndNumbers, CONVERT(int, (RAND() * LEN(@CharsAndNumbers)) + 1), 1),
        SUBSTRING(@CharsAndNumbers, CONVERT(int, (RAND() * LEN(@CharsAndNumbers)) + 1), 1),
        SUBSTRING(@CharsAndNumbers, CONVERT(int, (RAND() * LEN(@CharsAndNumbers)) + 1), 1)
    )
```

[Testing SQL in StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/706686)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing something like this:

```
declare @chars varchar(255);
set @chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789';

declare @i int;
set @i = 1;

declare @automateKey = varchar(255);

set @automatekey = '';

while @i <= 5
begin
    set @automateKey = @automateKey + substring(@chars, cast(rand() * len(@chars) + 1 as int), 1)
    set @i = @i + 1;
end;
```

This solution has two main components.  First, all the valid characters are defined as a string.  Second, it uses a `while` loop to set the values using `rand()`.

`rand()` behaves in a strange way in SQL Server -- it is evaluated only once for a given query when it appears.  Hence, I generally do not want to use it in a `SELECT` statement.

I should add that the following can replace the `WHILE` loop:

```
set @automateKey = (substring(@chars, cast(rand() * len(@chars) + 1 as int), 1) +
                    substring(@chars, cast(rand() * len(@chars) + 1 as int), 1) +
                    substring(@chars, cast(rand() * len(@chars) + 1 as int), 1) +
                    substring(@chars, cast(rand() * len(@chars) + 1 as int), 1) +
                    substring(@chars, cast(rand() * len(@chars) + 1 as int), 1)
                   );
```

Comment: `declare @automateKey = varchar(255);` remove the = sign.

Answer (score 0):

Your key seems to have 3 parts:

First character is random number 0-10 which is genereted with:

```
(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%10)
```

Second character is random letter which is generated with:

```
CHAR(ascii('A')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25))
```

Third part is three characters that could be either letter or number

```
LEFT(newid(),@count)
```

It's not hard to change the first two parts to eliminate unwanted characters, but would require bit of changing to third part. 
Instead you can just leave this as is, and add to the end while loop to search and replace unwanted characters - 0 and 1 with random number, O and L with random letter:

```
DECLARE @automateKey VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @Length INT = 6
DECLARE @Count INT = 2

SET @Length = @Length + 1
SET @Count = @Count + 1
--this seems unnecessary , why not just SET @Count = 3 ?

SELECT @automateKey =  
      (SELECT CAST((ABS(Checksum(NewId())) % 10) AS VARCHAR(1)) + 
              CHAR(ascii('A')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25)) +
              LEFT(newid(),@count) Random_Number)

WHILE (@automateKey LIKE '%0%' OR @automateKey LIKE '%1%')
BEGIN
    SELECT @automateKey = REPLACE(@automateKey, '0', (Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%10))
    SELECT @automateKey = REPLACE(@automateKey, '1', (Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%10))
END

WHILE (@automateKey LIKE '%O%' OR @automateKey LIKE '%L%')
BEGIN
    SELECT @automateKey = REPLACE(@automateKey, 'O', CHAR(ascii('A')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25)))
    SELECT @automateKey = REPLACE(@automateKey, 'L', CHAR(ascii('A')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25)))
END

SELECT @automateKey
```

Comment: many thanks for ur support, but how can i include this one into insert script as input value to table, and i need to have only 5 character random generation key ..

Comment: The same you did before? There are just two extra loops between generating key and using it.